# Accessing content from <ng-content> passed through ngProjectAs via @ContentChild

Tags: angular, angular13, transclusion

So I have a setup where I have a layout component that uses multi-slot approach making certain sections of my page customizable:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  ContentChild,
  AfterViewInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { FooterComponent } from '../footer/footer.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from '../header/header.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  template: `<div>
  <div *ngIf="header" style="border-style: dotted;">
    <h2>Header:{{ header.title }}</h2>
    <ng-content select="app-header"></ng-content>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h2>Content</h2>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
  <p>End of Content</p>
  <div *ngIf="footer" style="border-style: dashed;">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
    <ng-content select="app-footer"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>`,
})
export class LayoutComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChild(HeaderComponent)
  public header?: HeaderComponent;

  @ContentChild(FooterComponent)
  public footer?: FooterComponent;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('Injected', this.header, this.footer);
  }
}
```

Notice that I use `@ContentChild` to inject and display specific elements on demand.
Now I want to create a more specialized component that pre-populates the footer:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested-layout',
  template: `<app-layout>
  <ng-content select="app-header" ngProjectAs="app-header"></ng-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <app-footer>
    <p>Predefined Footer</p>
  </app-footer>
</app-layout>
`,
})
export class NestedLayoutComponent {}
```

Then I would use `NestedLayoutComponent` like this:

```
<app-nested-layout>
  <app-header title="Header">
    <p>Header stuff</p>
  </app-header>
  Regular content
</app-nested-layout>
```

I use `ngProjectAs` here so that `app-layout` actually recognizes the content. The problem is that even though the `ngProjectAs` correctly places the content into the right place in the DOM. the `@ContentChild` annotation for injecting the header component will not work in `LayoutComponent` and yields an `undefined`.

Is this maybe related to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16299)?

I have also put together the whole example into [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mag2v5?file=app/nested-layout/nested-layout.component.ts)

Comment: if you remove ngProjectAs from your NestedLayoutComponent at still renders the content in the app-header is not that what you are looking for?

Comment: @MehyarSawas If I remove the `ngProjectAs` it will not end up in the `<ng-content select="app-header"></ng-content>` slot of `LayoutComponent` in the first place, but instead will end up in `<ng-content></ng-content>`. I modified the stiles to illustrate this a little bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible Solution**

You could pass the `headerComponent` as an [@Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input) from the `NestedLayoutComponent` to the `LayoutComponent` and there you check whether the `header` is defined, which is a direct child of the `LayoutComponent` or the `parentHeader` is defined which is the direct child of the `NestedLayoutComponent`.

Here is my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-soourl?file=app/nested-layout/nested-layout.component.ts)

Your NestedLayoutComponent Template:

```
<app-layout [parentHeader]="header">
  <ng-content select="app-header" ngProjectAs="app-header"></ng-content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <app-footer>
    <p>Predefined Footer</p>
  </app-footer>
</app-layout>
```

Your LayoutComponent Class:

```
...
 @ContentChild(HeaderComponent)
  public header?: HeaderComponent;

  @Input() parentHeader: HeaderComponent;
...
```

Your LayoutComponent Template:

```
<div *ngIf="header || parentHeader" style="border-style: dotted; margin-top: 10px">
    <h2>Header:{{ header.title }}</h2>
    <ng-content select="app-header"></ng-content>
  </div>
...
```

Feel free pass the `HeaderComponent` further to the `NestedLayoutComponent` by  your favorite way.

**Explained**

The [@ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) header is `undefined` in the `LayoutComponent`, because the `HeaderComponent` in this case is not a content child of the `LayoutComponent`, but a content child of the `NestedLayoutComponent`. Even though angular projects the content in a child component by selector, still when querying with [@ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) the content child element must be a real child in the component template.
In your example under `AppComponent` the `app-header` is a child of `app-nested-layout` and `app-layout` in `app-nested-layout` is does not have the `app-header` as a child content.

Comment: Jep thats a good way to solve it :) Thanks!